# How to bind Java object to HTML form using Spring MVC and Pebble template engine

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, modelandview, pebble

I am having trouble getting [Pebble](https://github.com/PebbleTemplates/pebble) template engine to display Java object values in HTML form in a HTTP GET request.

In Pebble template I have a form like this.

```
<form name="userDetailsForm" action="/update-details" method="post">
    <label>Email Address: </label>
    <input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress">
</form>
```

In Spring MVC I have

```
@GetMapping("/update-details")
public ModelAndView showUpdateDetails()
{
    UserDetailsForm form = new UserDetailsForm();
    form.setEmailAddress("example@example.com");
    return new ModelAndView("update_details_template", "userDetailsForm", form);
}
```

When I load the page in browser, the email input field is blank. I would like the email input field to be populated with "example@example.com". How can I achieve this? Is Pebble able to bind Java objects to HTML forms in a HTTP Get request?

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="text" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" value="{{userDetailsForm.emailAddress}}">`?

Comment: Yes, value="{{userDetailsForm.emailAddress}}" works. But I was hoping Spring can automatically bind the form object to HTML like it can for Thymeleaf. I guess this is not possible for Pebble.